# Merge pdf files with PDFBox using CLI

Tags: java, cmd, command-line-interface, pdfbox

I found PDFBox by Apache but what do I for example write in the cmd?

http://pdfbox.apache.org/commandlineutilities/PDFMerger.html

tried `java -jar pdfbox-app-1.6.0.jar PDFMerger C:\f\test1.pdf,C:\f\test1.pdf C:\f\new.pdf` for example

Can I also get the list of the PDFs to merge from a dir automatically for merging?

Got it:

`java -jar pdfbox-app-1.6.0.jar PDFMerger C:\f\test1.pdf C:\f\test1.pdf C:\f\new.pdf`

In the end I used:
`java -jar pdfbox-app-1.6.0.jar PDFMerger C:\f\*.pdf C:\f\new.pdf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it:

`java -jar pdfbox-app-1.6.0.jar PDFMerger C:\f\test1.pdf C:\f\test1.pdf C:\f\new.pdf`

In the end I used:
`java -jar pdfbox-app-1.6.0.jar PDFMerger C:\f\*.pdf C:\f\new.pdf`